# jQuery selector: all but n first in a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

So I have a list of siblings like so;

```
  <div class="b"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="c"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
```

(**Note:** The `b`'s are **not** children of the `a`'s, they're all siblings. Indentation is for emphasis.)

In jQuery, I need to select each `b`, forgoing the first *n* elements in a streak. There is no specific type/class of element that breaks the streak, nor any dependable number of `b`'s in a streak, or non-`b` elements in between.

If I used the selector to add a class `selected`, and supposing *n* = 2, my DOM would then look like so;

```
  <div class="b"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b selected"></div>
  <div class="b selected"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
<div class="a"></div>
<div class="c"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b selected"></div>
  <div class="b selected"></div>
  <div class="b selected"></div>
  <div class="b selected"></div>
  <div class="b selected"></div>
```

In other words, select every `b` except for *n* elements after anything else than `b`, or the beginning.

I've tried `:nth-child(n+3)`, but that simply seems to take all the `b`'s into account, despite the `a`'s that break them.

I also tried fiddling around with `.nextUntil()` and `.filter()`, but it must take a better man than me to crack this. Ideas?

Comment: The `.a`'s are not breaking them. They are just present there as a separate `div`

Comment: Did you mean `:nth-child(n+3)`? The reason why it doesn't work as intended is because `:nth-child()` always counts *all* siblings from the very beginning under the same parent.

Comment: Good catch, edited the question. But yeah, trial and error taught me it doesn't apply to this case. Just thought I'd mention it before someone says 'what have you tried?'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since these elements are all siblings that share the same parent, some clever use of sibling combinators will do the trick:

```
$('.b + .b + .b').addClass('selected');
```

For any *n*, simply repeat `.b +` *n* times before the last `.b`.

No need for `:nth-child()` or any traversing/filtering functions, and is also a valid and well-supported CSS selector, in case you're looking to apply styles to these elements.

[jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/Mxc73)

---

If you need to add an intermediate element before each set of `.b + .b + .b` elements, add the class first, then prepend the intermediate element before the first of each set of those matched elements. The first of these elements can be matched by looking behind it for an element that *isn't* `.selected`, which excludes everything that *does* have a `.selected` directly behind it:

```
$('.b + .b + .b').addClass('selected')
                 .filter(':not(.selected) + .selected')
                 .before('<div class="inserted"></div>');
```

[Updated jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/Mxc73/1)

If chaining too many methods gets confusing, you can always do each step separately:

```
$('.b + .b + .b').addClass('selected');
$(':not(.selected) + .selected').before('<div class="inserted"></div>');
```

Comment: This is otherwise a solution I would've gone for, but I need to insert an element at the 'fold' point for *n*, for each streak. So after *n* `b`'s, insert element, add `.selected` for each element afterwards. The problem with `+` in this instance is that it would add the element in between every `b` after *n*. Using `.first()` wouldn't help since it would only apply to the first streak.

Comment: @Emphram Stavanger: I've updated my answer. Does it accomplish what you're looking for?

Comment: @BoltClock: that's awesome! I learned a couple of new things. Thank you! +1

Comment: Emphram and @Floyd Pink, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

css:

```
.b+.b+.b {
    color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vwrP6/